# Парсинг сайта, начать парсить сайт после полной загрузки

Tags: python, python-3.x

я хочу спарсить сайт, но он динамически подгружается(в начале 1 html, через время другой,пока подгрузиться)Я всегда получаю первый.Так вот, как бы так сделать, что бы он парсился через секунд 5-10) 
Код для примера
    import sys
    import time
    import requests
    import lxml.html

```
class JoobleParser:
    def __init__(self, base_url):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.last_time = ''

    def get_page(self):
        try:
            res = requests.get(self.base_url)
        except requests.ConnectionEror:
            return

        if res.status_code < 400:
            return res.content

    def parse(self, html):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = JoobleParser('site-my')

    page = parser.get_page()
    print(page.decode())
```

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы хотите парсить динамически загружаемые сайты, следует использовать selenium вместо requests. При этом в вашем случае следует обратить внимание сразу на следующие моменты:

1. Использовать WebDriverWait для ожидание окончания загрузки ресурса. Например, последним загружается ссылка с текстом "Print this article", в этом случае:

```
    ...
    driver.get(url)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT , 'Print this article')))
    # url - адрес целевой страницы сайта, driver - Selenium WebDriver
```

2. Важно также после загрузки страницы прокрутить её до конца. Например, посредством следующего кода:

```
    content = ''
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1)
        if content != driver.page_source:
            content = driver.page_source
            continue
        else:
            break

    # content - содержимое, driver - Selenium WebDriver
```